# Are Continuation Patents only available for patents filed in the USA and Australia?

Tags: discussion

Regarding Continuations Patents and all questions related to them and the work that is being undertaken for creating a Wiki on this subject, please can it be made clear in the Wiki and at the top of all the question and answer streams relating to this subject that Continuation Patents are unique to the USA and Australia and are not found anywhere else or available to any other country.This is not the case with Divisional Patents which are universally available throughout the PCT. Continuation Patents for patents granted in the USA only are of course open to all national based patents that file in the USA also, so it is difficult to claim that this system does not produce a level plying field for all but it does need to be clearly understood.

Comment: I am not aware of divisional patents available through the PCT route. Does anyone else have a clue about that? If not, then perhaps this question should be edited.

Comment: @chempatent1981 There's definitely no PCT divisional. But I don't think you can read too much into the question, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was quite unclear on what was being asked here, so I moved your question to Ask Patents Meta in the hope that I could give something of an answer, a site for asking questions and making suggestions about the site itself.

If you'd like to modify any content you see on the site (questions, answers, tag wikis, etc.), you're free to use the "edit" link below them. At that time, your suggestions will be placed in a queue for review by other users of the site before being published for everyone to see.

On the other hand, if you're concerned with modifying off-site material, could you please clarify what that would be?